# If condition is met start function again [LUA]

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a simple function to fill an array with random numbers

```
local function fillArray()
    local rand = math.random( 1,8 )
    if has_value(weaponOrder, rand) then
        -- I WANT TO RESTART FUNCTION HERE
        return false
    end
    return rand
end
for i = 1,8 do
    order[i] = fillArray()
end
```

I want if the condition is true (has_value is another function to check if the number exists again) to start the function again and return another result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`repeat-until`](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.3.html) statement.

```
local function fillArray()
  local rand
  repeat
    rand = math.random( 1,8 )
  until not has_value(weaponOrder, rand)
  return rand
end
```

Comment: I tried with repeat, but I couldn't figure out the arguments logic. Now I understand it. Thank you!